# Could you give me an example (if it exists) of an $A$-module $M$ that is finite and has a base?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

*Definition:

Let $A$ be a unit ring. A left $A-$module is a triple $(M, +, ·)$ such that $M$ is a set, $ + : M \times M \rightarrow M$ is an internal operation on $M$ and $·$ is what is called an external operation on $M$ with domain of operators on $A$, which simply means that $· : A \times M \rightarrow M$. Furthermore the following properties must be met:

1. $(r + s) + t = r + (s + t)$ for all $r, s, t \in M$.
2. $r + s = s + r$ for all $r, s \in M$.
3. There exists an element $0\in M$ such that $r + 0 = r$ for all $r \in M$.
4. For every $r\in M$ there exists an element $−r\in M$ such that $r + (−r) = 0$.
5. $a(r + s) = ar + as$ for all $a \in A$ and all $r, s \in M$.
6. $(a + b)r = ar + br$ for all $a, b \in A$ and all $r\in M$.
7. $a(br) = (ab)r$ for all $a, b \in A$ and all $r\in M$.
8. $1r = r$ for all $r \in M$.

*Context:

I've read that not every module has a basis. As example $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a $\mathbb Z-$ module but if it has a basis then the $\mathbb Z-$module $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ has to be isomorphic to the $\mathbb Z-$module $\mathbb Z^m$ (for some $m\in \mathbb N$). But it is not possible because $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is finite and $\mathbb Z^m$ not . So the $\mathbb Z-$ module $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ has not basis (by the way $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is also represented by $\mathbb Z_n$).

*Question:

Is it possible for an $A$-module $M$ to be finite and also have a basis?
If it exist. Could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There clearly is a finite module, and also has a basis.

You will know that we call $F$-module as $F$-vector space if $F$ is a field. And a vector space has a basis(which can be proven by Zorn's Lemma).

If $F$ is a finite field with $q$ elements(often written as $\Bbb F_q$), then $\Bbb F_q^n$ has $q^n$ elements, so it is finite. And it is $\Bbb F_q$-vector space, so it has a basis, like $\{e_i\mid1\le i\le n\}$.

Comment: In general, a finite free modules are (up to isomorphism) those of the form $R^n$, where $R$ is the base ring, which is finite, and $n$ is a non-negative integer, or the trivial module $\{0\}$. In particular, it is easy to check that there are no nonzero finite free modules over infinite rings.